# How do i have a 2011 bch transaction?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-cash, blockchain-fork

[image]

I was under the impression that BCH did not fork untill 2017.  How was i making transactions in 2011?

Comment: Altcoins like BCH copy both code and blockchain of bitcoin. The "blockchain" is the entire history that is copied to the alternative chain hence this transaction from 2011 is also copied and exists in original chain and the copy of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BCH chain shares all of the BTC history up until the point of the fork. If you're using the same address for BCH that you did for BTC in the past, any pre-fork BTC transactions will also appear as BCH transactions.

Comment: Thank you.  Im trying to claim those forked coins, but my coinbase wont give the private keys and im still running through my 4000 bitcoin core addresses; which so far are coming up 0.